# Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion on hidden field

Tags: zend-framework, flags, fieldset

Okay this is a weird one to me...Usually i get this error when there's a problem with the date/time format, but it's throwing up on a hidden field, even though it's set to view formhidden...Has this happened to anyone before?

[image]

That's the view:
    echo $this->formHidden($steppedEdge->get('glassSections'));

This is the form fieldset:

```
$this->add([
        'name'          =>  'glassSections',
        'type'          =>  \Zend\Form\Element\Hidden::class,
        'attributes'    =>  [
            'id'    => 'glassSections',
        ],
    ]);
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's because it was an entity in that field...